# Wordpress URL Change failed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[image]

I wanted to change the URL of a wordpress site. I changed the home and site_url entry in the mysql database table wp-options. After that the Login-Screen of the Wordpress Site changed and I am not able to login again.

Comment: You will have to change all the `url` in all tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run below queries to fix your issue.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_url', 'new_url') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_url','new_url');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_url', 'new_url');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'old_url', 'new_url');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_url', 'new_url');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'old_url', 'new_url');
```

For safety just take the backup of your database before executing above queries.

Comment: I have executed this queries in the phpmyadmin but the problem still appears.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both site_url and home in wp-options table.